# The directory name is invalid using msbuild FtpUploadDirectoryContent

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

i am working on msbuild scripts and getting below error message

```
 The "FtpUploadDirectoryContent" task failed unexpectedly.
error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid.
```

my scripts is

```
<FtpUploadDirectoryContent
        ServerHost="$(ftpHost)"
        Port="21"
        Username="$(ftpUser)"
        Password="$(ftpPass)"
        LocalDirectory="E:\demo\test.txt"
        RemoteDirectory="website/config"
        Recursive="true"
        />
```

my IIS hosted path is C:\inetpub\wwwroot and website\config folder is exist inside [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\config].but still i am getting message like **directory name is invalid**.please let me know how to resolve this issue.what is the proper systax for this..pls suggest if any othere thing is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LocalDirectory**="E:\demo\test.txt"

You gave it a file name, not a directory.

E:\demo\test.txt is a filename.

Here is the code from

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Ftp/FtpUploadDirectoryContent.cs

```
            try
            {
                UploadDirectory( LocalDirectory, "*.*", Recursive );
            }
            catch(FtpException caught)
            {
                Log.LogErrorFromException( caught, false );
                Log.LogError( "Couldn't upload directory." );
                return false;
            }


       foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles( localPath, mask ))
        {
            String filename = Path.GetFileName( file );
            Store( file, filename );

            Log.LogMessage( MessageImportance.Low, "{0} uploaded succesfully.", localPath );
        }
```

So what you're trying to do is essentially:

```
 Directory.GetFiles( "E:\demo\test.txt" , "*.* ))
```

which isn't going to work.

Change it to:

```
LocalDirectory="E:\demo\"
```

Example code from the github link above.

```
/// <Target Name="DeployWebsite">
/// <FtpUploadDirectoryContent
/// ServerHost="ftp.myserver.com"
/// Port="42"
/// Username="user"
/// Password="p@ssw0rd"
/// LocalDirectory="c:\build\mywebsite"
/// RemoteDirectory="root\www\mywebsite"
/// Recursive="true"
/// />
```

Note: LocalDirectory does not refer to a filename.

If you want to upload a single file, here is a possible alternative:

https://www.assembla.com/spaces/GHFtpTask/wiki/Home/history

The main features of FtpTask for MSBuild are:

```
**Upload, download or delete a single file on a FTP server** 
Recursively upload, download or delete a directory
Use multiple FTP connections simultaneously
```

FtpTask for MSBuild requires .NET 2.0.

Comment: i didn't get you?could you pls explain more?

Comment: so incase what about LocalDirectory and RemoteDirectory in side FtpUploadDirectoryContent. imean how to set path on it.

Comment: I would use a program like Filezilla to make sure your FTP is working correctly, ~then move the parameters to the <FtpUploadDirectoryContent> task.

Comment: thanks a lot ..now i got idea...it's working.but i wanted to ask if i have multiple file inside folder and only few file need to transer then incase how to set path?

Comment: but i have issue ,i want only selected file must be transfered.in your solution whatever file inside "c:\build\mywebsite"will be transer.so my question is how to transer only specific file

Comment: granadaCoder Are you there?pls suggest my above senario?

Comment: Sorry dude....... you'd have to modify the original source code........to put in a better "mask" (they are using "*.*" in the code.  That is why looking at the source code (if available) is important........ here is an in-general tip........ a msbuild task is basically an object where you can set some properties, and then it runs some dotnet code, there isn't any grand voodoo about it.  Looking at the source code is the best way to figure out what it can and cannot do.  from what I seen, that task cannot upload a single file.